# How to write a better XSLT when dealing with a potential loop in a loop situation?

Tags: xslt

I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row>
    <cell colname="1"><Name>SomeValue<Ref format="Ref" Idref="ABC"/></Name></cell>
    <cell colname="2"><Selection>
        <Config><Configuration>AAA</Configuration></Config>
        <Config><Configuration>BBB</Configuration></Config>
    </Selection></cell>
    <cell colname="6"><Notes>
        <Text><IteratorDef>
            <IteratorTag Id="ABC">DDi</IteratorTag>
            <IteratorList>
                <IteratorChoice>05</IteratorChoice>
                <IteratorChoice>10</IteratorChoice>
                <IteratorChoice>15</IteratorChoice>
            </IteratorList>
        </IteratorDef></Text>
    </Notes></cell>
</row>
```

I'd like to get the result like this:

The Ref points to the IteratorTag:
   There are two Configuration namely AAA and BBB. For each Configuration there are several IteratorChoice values. Each need to be concatenated with the Name value + IteratorTag value so SomeValue+DDi+05, SomeValue+DDi+10, and SomeValue+DDi+15.

```
   AAA
   SomeValueDDi05
   SomeValueDDi10
   SomeValueDDi15

   BBB
   SomeValueDDi05
   SomeValueDDi10
   SomeValueDDi15
```

My thought is write a loop in a loop with for-each keying on IteratorList and Configuration tags (Configuration loop will be inside IteratorList loop), is this the correct approach using XSLT ?.

TIA,

John

Comment: JohnX: Could you, please, edit the question and explain what are the rules that would cause those results to be produced? What result is produced by what node(s) of the source XML?

Comment: Dimitre: I'm done fixing some typos and added some more info.

Comment: JohnX: As a rule, one should use `xsl:apply-templates` in preference over `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: So basically an apply-templates inside an apply-templates ?.

Comment: OK let me try then. Thanks Dimitre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution1: this works only on provided input.
Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#13;'"/>

  <xsl:template match="row/cell/Selection/Config/Configuration">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,$newline)"/><!--AAA, BBB, etc-->

    <xsl:for-each select="/row/cell/Notes/Text/IteratorDef/IteratorList/IteratorChoice">
      <xsl:variable name="zstring" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::IteratorDef/IteratorTag">
        <xsl:variable name="ystring" select="concat(.,$zstring)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::row/cell/Name">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(.),$ystring,$newline)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <!--this is for extra line space after each CONFIGURATION block-->
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Edit: Solution 2.. I have used no reverse XPath but complete XPath ..
>   this works on robust XML. the method is slightly different .. here I
>   am going from high level (XPath) to lower level. This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#13;'"/>

  <xsl:template match="row/cell/Selection/Config/Configuration">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,$newline)"/><!--AAA, BBB, etc-->

    <xsl:for-each select="/row/cell/Name">
      <xsl:variable name="astring" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="/row/cell/Notes/Text/IteratorDef/IteratorTag">
        <xsl:variable name="bstring" select="concat($astring,normalize-space(.))"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="/row/cell/Notes/Text/IteratorDef/IteratorList/IteratorChoice">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($bstring,normalize-space(.),$newline)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <!--this is for extra line space after each CONFIGURATION block-->
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--disable all unwanted text nodes-->
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If this is your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row>
  <cell colname="1">
    <Name>
      SomeValue<Ref format="Ref" Idref="ABC"/>
    </Name>
  </cell>
  <cell colname="2">
    <Selection>
      <Config>
        <Configuration>AAA</Configuration>
      </Config>
      <Config>
        <Configuration>BBB</Configuration>
      </Config>
      <Config>
        <Configuration>CCC</Configuration>
      </Config>
    </Selection>
  </cell>
  <cell colname="6">
    <Notes>
      <Text>
        <IteratorDef>
          <IteratorTag Id="ABC">DDi</IteratorTag>
          <IteratorTag Id="ABC">EEi</IteratorTag>
          <IteratorList>
            <IteratorChoice>05</IteratorChoice>
            <IteratorChoice>10</IteratorChoice>
            <IteratorChoice>15</IteratorChoice>
            <IteratorChoice>20</IteratorChoice>
          </IteratorList>
        </IteratorDef>
      </Text>
    </Notes>
  </cell>
</row>
```

This would be your output:

```
AAA
SomeValueDDi05
SomeValueDDi10
SomeValueDDi15
SomeValueDDi20
SomeValueEEi05
SomeValueEEi10
SomeValueEEi15
SomeValueEEi20

BBB
SomeValueDDi05
SomeValueDDi10
SomeValueDDi15
SomeValueDDi20
SomeValueEEi05
SomeValueEEi10
SomeValueEEi15
SomeValueEEi20

CCC
SomeValueDDi05
SomeValueDDi10
SomeValueDDi15
SomeValueDDi20
SomeValueEEi05
SomeValueEEi10
SomeValueEEi15
SomeValueEEi20
```

Comment: you can use one or more `Name` values.

Comment: Looks good, I did similar thing with for-each loop in a loop. Thinking how to use apply-templates currently. Thanks!.

Comment: I will try that solution as well. :)